# Is there a hook point after the html is rendered in Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an hook point after the html is rendered  and before it is sent client side in Asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [OnResultExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuted.aspx) in either your controller or via an action filter attribute.

Comment: fantastic so how do I access the html being sent?

Comment: You don't typically get access to the HTML through that.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Inspired by less and sass, I want to write a fluent c# api that will build and insert css into the file. This api should also have a toCSS function to translate the css. So it can be only used to write complicated CSS. eliminates additional files and is testable.  etc

Comment: @Joe I've done something similar with analytics. My approach was to build up an analytics model in the ViewBag then render a strongly-typed partial view that output the analytics code in the master page. Because the views render to a stream I think that you'd have trouble injecting more either before or after the framework renders the page. I didn't go this far, but you could perhaps extend the standard view engine to handle this as well.  Good luck!